# How do i combine character arrays char *foo = (char *bar1 + char *bar2 + char *bar3)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two prefilled arrays as follows:

```
char *query1;
char *query2;
```

and one array that is filled by the user.

```
char *username;
```

what i want to do is combine these into one for example

```
char *SQLquery;
```

i have try'd working with strlen and strcat in this way:

```
        if (query==3) {

        char *query1 = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='";
        char *username = "DEFSER"; //prefilled this for test purpuse
        char *query2 = "'";

        SQLquery = new char[strlen(query1)+strlen(username)+strlen(query2)+1];
        *SQLquery = '/0';

        strcat(SQLquery,query1);
        strcat(SQLquery,username);
        strcat(SQLquery,query2);

        strcpy(laArray[0][2],SQLquery);
        }
```

there is no compiler error however when i print my laArray[0][2] or my SQLquery it returns 0.

did i do something wrong?

Comment: Decide if you work with c or c++, you use c-style strings but also `new`. In c++ you could just work with std::string

Comment: Why don't you use std::string? Do you plan to escape the user input in some ways, or you just put it there in the sql statement (I would not do that)

Comment: In C++ use `std::string`. Even in C, never use `char*`, use `const char*`

Comment: How do you allocate memory for `laArray[0][2]` ? Why did you use `strcpy(laArray[0][2],SQLquery);` ? Do you keep a trace of `SQLquery` elsewhere ? Use `malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(query1)+strlen(username)+strlen(query2)+1));`, Try something like `laArray[0][2]=SQLquery;` and `free(laArray[0][2])` somewhere (if c, not c++)

Comment: thanks BLUEPIXY. that was the problem.

Comment: how are you printing? I don't see any `printf` or `std::cout` statements.

Comment: BLUEPIXY could you make a answer so i can approve it?

Comment: srini i dont use command line... i use a game library to print the char* arrays

Comment: It is better practice to set the memory to null using `memset`.

Comment: @Manu343726 Don't use const char * if you need a dynamic array. For those who don't know const char * makes a character pointer to a character that cannot be changed by dereferencing the pointer. This is the correct thing to do for a string constant (since what it points to is read-only) but not for a dynamically allocated string.

Comment: post a complete, compilable example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: consider what happens when Little Bobby Tables uses your program

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use `C`, use the following

```
const char query1[] = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='";
char *username = "DEFSER";

SQLquery = malloc(strlen(query1) + strlen(username) + strlen(query2) + 1 + 1);

sprintf("%s%s'", query1, username);
laArray[0][2] = SQLquery;  /* Based on comments, I believe this is what you want to do */
...
/* Do whatever you want to do with laArray */
...
laArray[0][2] = NULL;
free(SQLquery);
SQLquery = NULL;
```

If you plan to use `C++`, use the `std::string` like following

```
std::string SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='";
std::string username = "DEFSER";

SQLquery += username;
SQLquery += '\'';
laArray[0][2] = SQLquery;  /* if laArray is 2D array of string, const_cast<char *>(SQLquery.c_str()) if it contains pointers */
/* Do whatever you want to do with laArray */
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use direct '+' concatenation in C. In C++ you could overload an `operator`, but it would be much smarter to use `std::string`, which already overloads the `operator+` and then extract `c_str()` out of it to get `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand BLUEPIXY has already spotted the real issue, but just to add another option, you could use sprintf_s(...) to do your string concatenation and potentially provide some more control over formatting (should that be required).

For the suggestions of using std::string (if in C++): you'll need to use the c_str() method to access the char* from std::string if you need to convert back to a old-style C char string.

Good luck.

Comment: i use CGL (Core Media Library) i print it like this:
CGL_DrawText(10,50,font, "Username: %s Fullname: %s Email: %s Password: %s",laArray[0][2],laArray[0][3],laArray[0][4],laArray[0][5]);